# Ubuntu isnt accepting password

Tags: login, password

I type in the correct password during login, but it still comes back to the same window. I tried Ctrl+alt+F1 and I can log in but when I try to use the commands like ls or sudo, it shows /bin isn't in path environment. What can I do to actually log in without losing data. 
I'm using 18.04 LTS

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB. If you know how to chroot, then you have the skills to fix your system from there. If you don't know how to chroot, then backup your data to a safe media and reinstall.

Comment: You should still be able to run commands using their full paths (ex. `/bin/ls`, `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment`) and fix whatever edits you made that have screwed up your `PATH` variable

Comment: Thanks man. That will be helpful. I did it by going into recovery mode and opening root shell there